# main.xml hiding the view help

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-manifest

I am unable to display both the setContentView(R.layout.main) and View together. I think I am not getting the concept right. Could anyone explain me where I am going wrong. Thank you. //please read the comment in code

I am trying to display a image on main.xml using BitmapFactory.

```
   public class TryGraph extends Activity 
 {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);//I think this is where I need your help
    setContentView(new myView(this));//I want this to be displayed in main.xml
}

private class myView extends View{

    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sinewave);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0,
                300, 143);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, 60, 50, null);
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawRect(250,255,260,250, myPaint);

    }
}
```

}

THE XML FILE IS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setContentView` you are telling the device to load the entire layout that should be displayed to the user.  In most cases this view will occupy the entire screen. Now this Layout file is considered the root and may contain child views, one of which should be your ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView   
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:text="hello world"
    >  
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sampleimage"
    />
<?LinearLayout>
```

This ImageView can now be accessed by code through the use of `findViewById(R.id.myImageView)` and you can then use the `BitmapFactory` to set your image. If the image is not going to be changed, you can just set it in the layout file `android:src="@drawable/sampleimage"`